# how to use a .wav from a project folder

Tags: java, eclipse, wav

So this is what I want to do.  I want to load an `.wav` music file from my project folder.  I have done this with a image, as displayed below.  I want to do this with an audio file.  Is this possible? Is there an easy way to convert my old method to a new one.  The reason I want to do this is because I want to have all the files for my program in a `.jar` file so I can just send that and it plays.

```
static audiotest music = new audiotest( "C:\\WINDOWS\\Media\\POL-purple-hills-short.wav" );
music.start();

URL mountainImage2 = Main.class.getResource("Mountains.png");
mountainImage = ImageIO.read(mountainImage2);
```

Comment: maybe you can open it with some external app. I don't think eclipse comes with a java media player

Comment: What do you need help with specifically? Are you having a problem with the URL or are you asking how to play sound?

Comment: What I am trying to do is load and open an audio file from my project folder.

Comment: If you want to distribute all media resources in jar file you need to get your resource (like you do with image) and modify your audiotest constructor (pass URL or InputStream as parameter)